# passing an struct array into another file

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

I want to make a bubble sort using a pointer like this, but when I compile it I get diagnostics that say that `p` and `q` haven't been initialized. Does anybody know how to initialize these two struct pointers?  Here is the sort function:

```
//this is my another file source code
    #include "my_sort.h"
    void my_sort(REC rec, int n){
        REC *p, *q,*tmp;
        int i,j;
        for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
            *p = rec;
            for(j=1;j<n;j++){
                *q = rec;
                q++;
                if(p->score > q->score){
                    *tmp= *p;
                    *p=*q;
                    *q=*tmp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am calling it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "my_sort.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  FILE *fp;
  REC rec[MAX_NUM];
  int i;
  int sum , min, max , n;
    
  my_sort(rec, n); //at this point i want to pass the REC rec array into another file

  return 0;
}
```

By the way, inside `my_sort.h` is the initialization of `REC` structure, and for the value of rec array struct, the `main` function is reading a text file.

Comment: You don't pass arguments to file, you pass arguments to *functions*. Which you are doing. But not correctly. You want to pass a pointer to the first element of the array to your function (which have the type `REC *`) but the function doesn't want a pointer. That leads to an error.

Comment: Also, inside the sorting function, the variable `p`, `q` and `tmp` are defined as pointers, but *where do they point*? You never make them point anywhere, which means they are uninitialized and with *indeterminate* values (look at them as garbage). Attempting to dereference such a pointer leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: thanks for the comment. for the p and q i want to point the first and second value of the rec structure array but i don't know how to do that. how can i point the first and second value of the array but the struct is not initialize as an array anymore?

Comment: What's the definition of `REC`? Please provide a [mre].

Comment: If `rec` in (in the `my_sort` function) was a pointer, then the first element is `rec[0]` and the second element is `rec[1]`. You get pointers to them by using the pointer-to operator `&` as usual: `&rec[0]` and `&rec[1]`. You assign these pointers to the variables `p` and `q` like normal, for example `p = &rec[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

The most fundamental problem with your code is that this function signature ...

> ```
>     void my_sort(REC rec, int n)
> ```

... is not matched with this function call ...

> ```
>   REC rec[MAX_NUM];
>   int i;
>   int sum , min, max , n;
>
>   my_sort(rec, n); //at this point i want to pass the REC rec array into another file
> ```

Function `my_sort` expects its first parameter to be a (single) `REC`, but the main function is passing an array (which decays to a pointer, `REC *`).  Your compiler ought to be warning you about that, or else warning you that you are calling a function without an in-scope prototype.  If it is not doing so then you should either turn up the warning level or get a better compiler.

In any case, that issue needs to be corrected at `my_sort()`.  A parameter of type `REC` is not an appropriate input for sorting an array of objects of that type.  The correct match to the call, and almost surely the correct one for what you actually want the function to do, would be

```
    void my_sort(REC *rec, int n)
```

.  Alternatively, this variation means exactly the same thing, but some people find it more intuitive:

```
    void my_sort(REC rec[], int n)
```

In both cases, the type of parameter `rec` is `REC *`, and it will receive a pointer to the first `REC` in the array.

**And that leads directly into the main question**: how do you initialize the `p` and `q` pointers?  Having defined `rec` appropriately (as above), these will be other pointers into the same array, so a natural way would involve pointer arithmetic based on `rec`.  For example,

```
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        p = rec + i;
        for(j=1;j<n;j++){
            q = rec + j;
            // NO q++;
```

Note well, and this is the second key point, that that assigns values *to the pointers themselves*, which is an altogether separate consideration from values of the objects to which they point. That is exactly the subject of the diagnostics you reported.